# REST API: Should POST/PUT form data contains form name?

Tags: rest, api

I'm quite new to REST API and currently in a hurry building an app.
Just want to ask the question for clarification before the system's codes get bigger.
What's the best practice in the long run? What if there's a two categories in a form, such as user and item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit subjective, but generally if you have 2 distinct forms, it might be better to send them to 2 different endpoints: `POST /new-user` and `POST /new-item`.

Comment: It looks like it's not what I wanted to know but what if I only have one form which includes two models or categories then send it to an endpoint? should form name be appropriate? 

Let's say a form is in update mode, the user can update user details and item details then the user press submit. should the form data be grouped? If yes, will it conforms to REST being stateless?

Please enlighten me. :)

Comment: What stateless means in HTTP is that you can break the TCP connection, re-connect, do the request and it will work the same as if you never broke the (keepalive) TCP connection. It's almost impossible to create stateful HTTP applications, and there's no such thing as 'conformant with REST' because REST is not a standard. If you want more guidance, it's better to follow a specific standard for API's such as JSON-API, or HAL, Siren, GraphQL, etc.

Comment: Is it wrong to send 2 entities in 1 HTTP request? It kind of depends who you ask. One way to look at this is that you don't send 2 entities, but you send one combined super-entity. Most REST folks will agree it's probably better to have 2 resources, and 2 PUT requests and only resort to combinding resources if you have a good reason to do so.